# How do I make Visual Studio forget a password previously used for a PFX file?

Tags: visual-studio, pfx

We sign our assemblies with a standard PFX file.  In the past, we used a different PFX file with a different password.  That older password doesn't exist on our build server.  I would like to make sure it no longer exists on my developer PC so I can spot build errors before they get to the build server.

How can I make my local developer PC forget this stored password?